# How to disable Nancy's JSON to C# class auto case conversion for Dictionary<string, T>?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, nancy

How can Nancy's automatic conversion between camel and Pascal casing during serialization to and deserialization from JSON be disabled for objects representing dictionaries in C# **and** JavaScript?

In my case the keys of these dictionaries are IDs that must not be changed by the automatic case conversion.

Additionally, these dictionaries themselves are values of other object's property names / keys.

Here is an example JavaScript object, where I **want** the auto case conversion for the object (`.customers` to `.Customers` and `.addresses` to `.Addresses`), but not for the ID-value sub-objects' keys (`ID33100a00`, `abc433D123`, etc.):

```
{
    customers: {
        ID33100a00: 'Percy',
        abc433D123: 'Nancy'
    },
    addresses: {
        abc12kkhID: 'Somewhere over the rainbow',
        JGHBj45nkc: 'Programmer\'s hell',
        jaf44vJJcn: 'Desert'
    }
}
```

These dictionary objects are all represented by `Dictionary<string, T>` in C#, e.g.:

```
Dictionary<string, Customer> Customers;
Dictionary<string, Address> Addresses;
```

Unfortunately setting

```
JsonSettings.RetainCasing = true;
```

would result in no auto case conversion at all.

I also tried to solve the problem by writing my own `JavaScriptConverter`
as described in [Nancy documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Extending-Serialization-with-Converters),
but the actual serialization/deserialization to/from strings
for the keys of objects takes place somewhere else
(because the converter does not handle JSON strings directly,
but `IDictionary<string, object>` objects).

I read about a related "bug" (or behavior) [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1484).

Answer (score 3):

In our projects we usually depend on Newtonsoft.Json for our serializing needs.
And how we get the proper casing, is by creating a new class inheriting from JsonSerializer, like so:

```
public sealed class CustomJsonSerializer : JsonSerializer
{
    public CustomJsonSerializer()
    {    
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    }
}
```

And then register it with the Application like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
{
    base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);
    container.Register<JsonSerializer,CustomJsonSerializer>().AsSingleton();            
}
```

It also allows you to customize other bits of serialization, Like getting enums Serialized as strings:

```
public CustomJsonSerializer()
{
    Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This means I would have to use Newtonsoft.Json as replacement at some point where Nancy does the conversion from the JSON string to the `IDictionary<string, object>` object. By the way: Nancy also supports the enum string conversion by using `JavaScriptPrimitiveConverter`.